# getInitialProps does not return data as expected from Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`getInitialProps` does not return data as expected from Server.

Until in from browser return fine.

Explanation and code:

Open page and `getInitialProps` should return the webSocket URL parametar from server.

But returns undefined value.

I checked from backend `wsUrl` is sent correctly.

```
static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    if (req) {

     // WRONG: IN THIS CASE `wsUrl` value is undefiend 
      const { wsUrl } = req;
      return { collections: req.user.collections, email: req.user.id, wsUrl };
    }
    // IN THIS CASE I AM GETTING THE `wsUrl` value
    const { wsUrl } = await getWebSocketUrl();

    return {
      wsUrl
    };
  }
```

Any idea What is the problem?

Comment: It will be helpful, if you can put the data of 'req' you are getting before you checking it in if condition

Comment: `wsUrl` Is not in req - I checked

Comment: when this `getInitialProps()` is calling you are passing a argument does that argument contain the wsUrl value before callling the function